# Changing the file's creation timestamp in Linux programmatically in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems

The `statx()` system call was added to Linux kernel and now it is possible to get the creation (birth) time of the file from `statx.stx_btime` stucture field on supported filesystems. But I can't find any support in `utimensat()` of similar system calls.

Is it possible to change file's creation timestamp in C/C++ and how?

Comment: Why would you want to change the *creation* timestamp of a file? What problem is that supposed to solve? Besides, does it really make any sens to do it? To falsify history like that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need to make a copy of the file with the same timestamps (btime, atime and mtime) like original file in my backup application.

Comment: So you want to *clone* the file? If you search using that term (clone) do you get better hits then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The cloning file is useless in my case. Backuped files are stored in my backup tool database in different way than in the source filesystems. When I am recovering file from database to the target filesystem I need to create the new file and then change its timestamps. That is reason why I need to directly change timestamps of the file.

Comment: As a forensic investigator, I would say you really should not do that. There should be no downside to ignoring the birth timestamp from a back-up perspective.

Comment: @Cheatah Could you give some arguments why it isn't good to restore the birth timestamp of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`statx.stx_btime` is filesystem-specific. Linux has only three standardized timestamps - ctime, atime, and mtime - which are filled by the filesystem-agnostic [generic_fillattr](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/stat.c#L43) function.

Creation time on the other hand is filled by filesystem-specific functions, for instance with ext4 you can see the relevant code [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext4/inode.c#L5544):

```
int ext4_getattr(struct user_namespace *mnt_userns, const struct path *path,
         struct kstat *stat, u32 request_mask, unsigned int query_flags)
{
    struct inode *inode = d_inode(path->dentry);
    struct ext4_inode *raw_inode;
    struct ext4_inode_info *ei = EXT4_I(inode);
    unsigned int flags;

    if ((request_mask & STATX_BTIME) &&
        EXT4_FITS_IN_INODE(raw_inode, ei, i_crtime)) {
        stat->result_mask |= STATX_BTIME;
        stat->btime.tv_sec = ei->i_crtime.tv_sec;
        stat->btime.tv_nsec = ei->i_crtime.tv_nsec;
    }
...
```

There seems to be no easy way to access the creation time - a quick search reveals that ext4's `i_crtime` is not directly modifiable.

A possible solution is to write a filesystem-specific driver to modify e.g. `i_crtime` directly - but this carries its own risks in modifying internal filesystem data.